# What’s old school number?

Tags: meaning

I’d like to ask about the sentence from The Retired Colourman by Conan Doyle.

> It chanced to be my old school number, thirty-one, and so is stuck in
>   my head.

I’m not sure of this school number thing Dr. Watson brought up. Would someone tell me which is more likely..
A: A number given to each student while they belong to the school.
B: A number to distinguish each school, as in 87th Precinct.

Thanks.

Comment: I would guess that it's the number assigned to the school.  But it really doesn't matter.

Comment: The *'old school number, thirty-one'* can be traced back to an 11 year old Arthur Ignatius Conan Doyle wrote to his mother *'PS My number is 31 like last year.'*. This is documented in  *Arthur Conan Doyle: A Life in Letters*. I cannot find enough online text from that letter to determine the content (student number, school team number, class number, dormitory number, etc) but a full examination of the letter should explain the meaning for you. I doubt that it is a school identifier since his mother should know if he was at the same school as last year.

Comment: A..............

Comment: @HotLicks Watson would have been a middle to upper middle class person (otherwise he would not have become a doctor in Victorian Britain). This means that he was, almost certainly, educated in a fee-paying school if not a Public School (that's a British Public School which is the exact opposite of an American public school). None of those schools would have been numbered, they all had names so Watson's 'school number' must have been some sort of roll number.